# Nested while loop for API json collection

Tags: python, json, api, while-loop, python-requests

I'm requesting 590 pages from the Meetup API. I've iterated with a while loop to get the pages. Now that I have the pages I need to request this pages and format them correctly as python in order to place into a Pandas dataframe.

> This is how it looks when you do it for **one** url :

```
url = ('https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=1&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3')
r = requests.get(url).json()
data = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r['results'])
```

> But because I have so many pages I want to do this automatically and iterate through them all.

That's how nested while loops came to mind and this is what I tried:

```
urls = 0
offset = 0

url = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=%d&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3'

r = requests.get(urls%d = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=%d&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3').json()

while urlx < 591:
   new_url = r % urls % offset
   print(new_url)

   offset += 1
```

However, it isn't working and I'm receiving many errors including this one:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Looks like the issue is with `urls%d` on line, `requests.get(urls%d = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/...`. That is not a valid python syntax.

Comment: urlx is not defined and even if it was in some code earlier, it doesn't change its value in the loop `while urlx < 591:`. This will lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, and the code has lots of issues.

But if you just want to loop through 0 to 591 and fetch URLs, then here's the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

base_url = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=%d&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3'

for i in range(0, 592):
    url = base_url % i
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    print("Fetching URL: %s\n" % url)

    # do something with r here
    # here I'll append it to a list of dfs

    dfs.append(pd.io.json.json_normalize(r['results']))
```